# .txt File not showing up in Bootstrap modal using PHP's file I/O methods

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

My current issue is that when a link is clicked in a table, the modal that gets triggered does not display a .txt file given in the PHP code. The PHP statement  is nested in the HTML `<p>`and `<pre>`  paragraph statement and uses the `fopen` and `fread` methods. The code, once executed, only shows an empty box.

```
<div id=<?php echo "$id"; ?> class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true"   style="display: none;">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header"><button aria-hidden="true" class="close"data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>

         <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo "$first_name $last_name"; ?></h4>
           </div>

    <div class="modal-body"><img src="empty_profile.gif" width="200px" height="200px" alt="Pic goes here"><br>
    <a href="mail goes here" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Mail</a>    
     <p>
      <pre>
        <?php
          $file = fopen("358.txt", "r") or die("txt not found!!1");
          $read=fread($file);
          echo "$read";
          fclose($file);?> 
      </pre>    
    </p>    
   </div>
```

The best place for the PHP file i/o, in my opinion, is inside the "modal-body" class div, as the format structure of the modal would only allow for it to be right after the header. How can I get the file contents to show in my modal?

Comment: If you want to use `fread` you need the length of the file or iterate in chunks until end of file is hit.

Comment: What's up with all this `echo "$somevar"`? You don't need to wrap variables in quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `fread` incorrectly (you're missing the `length` argument).

Instead, do as the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.fread.php) suggests and use `file_get_contents` instead...

> **Note**:
>   If you just want to get the contents of a file into a string, use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php) as it has much better performance than the code above.

For example

```
<pre>
  <?= is_readable('358.txt') ? file_get_contents('358.txt') : 'txt not found!!1' ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: @keaner no idea what you're talking about. *"short codes"*?

Comment: `<?=` instead of `<?php echo`.  I understand the aversion to short tags (`<?`) because they only work if they are specifically enabled on your PHP install, but `<?=` should work regardless of settings since 5.4. At this point, it is a matter of preference really.

Comment: More information here ~ http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151694/8749

Comment: yup, just as he said above, short codes are not to be used, this is day one teaching, for the reason above. By using shortcuts you're assuming the host system has them enabled, Since 5.4 this SHOULD not matter but to be safe, simply use <?php always and forever :)